# Interpretation of [aDimension].[aHierarchy]

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, mdx

If I just write the following within an `MDX` script `[aDimension].[aHierarchy]` can it mean one of three different things depending on the context?

> 1. Specifies a hierarchy aHierarchy
> 2. Specifies the current member of aHierarchy i.e. is actually evaluated as [aDimension].[aHierarchy].currentmember
> 3. Specifies the default member of aHierarchy i.e. is actually evaluated as [aDimension].[aHierarchy].defaultmember

---

**EDIT**
An example of case 2 is the following where I believe `[Geography].[Geography].parent.NAME` is implicitly converted to `[Geography].[Geography].currentmember.parent.NAME`

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Parent] AS 
       [Geography].[Geography].parent.NAME
SELECT 
    NON EMPTY 
        {[Geography].[Geography].[Country]}
    ON ROWS,
    {[Measures].[Parent]} 
    ON COLUMNS
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say [2] is never done that way; you'll have to explicitly specify the currentMember function. [3] is an implicit conversion from hierarchy to member when a member is expected and you give a hierarchy instead.

Comment: I will add an example of a situation where it implicitly converts `[aDimension].[aHierarchy]` to `[aDimension].[aHierarchy].currentmember`